# How to stop javascript hover from activating all the other hovers?

Tags: javascript, hover

I have a couple pictures I want to hover when you do mouseenter but once you hover over one image, all the other images change to mouseenter as well. How do I stop this from happening so you can hover one at a time without affecting the others?

```
<p><IMG SRC="http://static1.squarespace.com/static/5736026127d4bd28d97e2b7a/t/5790f505b8a79bc462950c46/1469117701248/k_1.png/" ID="img1" onMouseEnter="doMouseenter()" onMouseLeave = "doMouseleave()"/></P>
```

```
<p><IMG SRC="http://static1.squarespace.com/static/5736026127d4bd28d97e2b7a/t/5790f584be65943e371ac3c8/1469117828984/k_2.png/" align="right" ID="img2" onMouseEnter="doMouseenter()" onMouseLeave = "doMouseleave()"/></P>
```

```
<script language="Javascript">
function doMouseenter() {
document.getElementById("img3").src = "http://static1.squarespace.com/static/5736026127d4bd28d97e2b7a/t/5790f6efd482e96f971b2dae/1469118191453/k_3_hover.png";
document.getElementById("img4").src = "http://static1.squarespace.com/static/5736026127d4bd28d97e2b7a/t/5790f7cc8419c25e40f16e6b/1469118412438/k_4_hover.png";
}

function doMouseleave() {
document.getElementById('img3').src = "http://static1.squarespace.com/static/5736026127d4bd28d97e2b7a/t/5790f603d482e96f971b24b2/1469117955279/k_3.png/";
document.getElementById('img4').src = "http://static1.squarespace.com/static/5736026127d4bd28d97e2b7a/t/5790f759b8a79bc462952502/1469118297585/k_4.png/";

}
```

Answer (score 0):

If you want, you can do like this:

```html
<p><IMG SRC="http://static1.squarespace.com/static/5736026127d4bd28d97e2b7a/t/5790f505b8a79bc462950c46/1469117701248/k_1.png/" ID="img1" onMouseEnter="this.src='http://static1.squarespace.com/static/5736026127d4bd28d97e2b7a/t/5790f6efd482e96f971b2dae/1469118191453/k_3_hover.png'" onMouseLeave = "this.src='http://static1.squarespace.com/static/5736026127d4bd28d97e2b7a/t/5790f603d482e96f971b24b2/1469117955279/k_3.png/'"/></p>



<p><IMG SRC="http://static1.squarespace.com/static/5736026127d4bd28d97e2b7a/t/5790f584be65943e371ac3c8/1469117828984/k_2.png/" align="right" ID="img2" onMouseEnter="this.src='http://static1.squarespace.com/static/5736026127d4bd28d97e2b7a/t/5790f7cc8419c25e40f16e6b/1469118412438/k_4_hover.png'" onMouseLeave = "this.src='http://static1.squarespace.com/static/5736026127d4bd28d97e2b7a/t/5790f759b8a79bc462952502/1469118297585/k_4.png/'"/></p>
```

Answer (score 0):

You're telling javascript to open both img3 and img4 when ever doMouseenter() is called.

This will modify the individual elements.

**HTML**

```
<p><img SRC="http://static1.squarespace.com/static/5736026127d4bd28d97e2b7a/t/5790f505b8a79bc462950c46/1469117701248/k_1.png/" ID="img1" onmouseover="doMouseenter(this)" onmouseout="doMouseleave(this)"></P>

<p><img SRC="http://static1.squarespace.com/static/5736026127d4bd28d97e2b7a/t/5790f584be65943e371ac3c8/1469117828984/k_2.png/" align="right" ID="img2" onmouseover="doMouseenter(this)" onmouseout="doMouseleave(this)"></P>
```

**JavaScript**

```
function doMouseenter(obj) {
    obj.style.opacity = 1;
}
function doMouseleave(obj) {
    obj.style.opacity = 0;
}
```